# Running an object call within an object call

Tags: c++, class, struct

I have a struct

```
  struct Stuff {

float something (int& prereq) {
float s = prereq+2;
return s;
}

double something_else(int& prereq_ref, float& thing_ref, float& s_ref ){
s2 = s + thing + h;
return s2;
}

};
```

Then I run a call in my main loop

```
float thing = 4;  
int prereq = 2;

int main() {

Stuff item;

    double n = item.something_else(prereq, thing, item.something(prereq));
return 0;

}
```

The call in main doesn't run, however the following line does

```
float s = item.something(prereq); 
double n = item.something_else(prereq, thing, s);
```

Am I missing something obvious? I'd rather not waste memory on what seems to be an unnecessary float.

Comment: i hink implicit conversions happen? try `item.something_else(prereq, thing, (float) item.something(prereq))`

Comment: `something()` returns a `float` by value.  `something_else()` accepts a `float` by reference.   For that to work, either `something_else()` needs to accept a `const` reference (which can bind a temporary, such as the return value from a function) or `something()` needs to return a reference to a `float` that continues to exist after it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float&` is an *lvalue reference* type. It can only take values that can be assigned to, such as variables.

```
float s = item.something(prereq); 
double n = item.something_else(prereq, thing, s);
```

Here, `s` is a variable. It has a place in memory and the expression `s = ...` would be meaningful. On the other hand,

```
double n = item.something_else(prereq, thing, item.something(prereq));
```

Here, the value is `item.something(prereq)`, which is *not* an lvalue. We can't write `item.something(prereq) = ...`; it doesn't make sense to assign to the return value of that function.

If you're not planning to modify the function arguments, take them by constant reference or by value.

```
double something_else(const int& prereq_ref, const float& thing_ref, const float& s_ref)
```

or

```
double something_else(int prereq_ref, float thing_ref, float s_ref)
```

for large data like structures or classes, you might consider using `const&`, but for integers and floats, it's unnecessary overhead and by-value parameters will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
int foo(int & arg);
```

This function signature says:
"I will take a reference to the variable you pass in, and I may change it while computing my return value."

If that statement is not true, then your function signature is wrong, or at least misleading to anyone looking at it.  It's also worth noting, that if you compute a temporary, it's not in a variable and so it's ineligible to pass into this function.  That is the problem you're running into.

Note, this style of function signature is what's known as an "out" parameter (non-const lvalue reference) because it can be thought of as returning an OUTput through a parameter.  This design approach is discouraged if other approaches are available, and so it is actually somewhat rare.  Any time you find a function with a non-const reference parameter, be sure it's what you mean.

Compare it to this:

```
int foo(int arg);
```

This function says:
"I get my own copy and don't care what it came from, variable, reference, temporary, whatever, and I will leave your origianl value alone when computing my return value."

This clearly is what you want to say, so drop the `&` in your parameter list.